# Get latest post from all categories except one

Tags: php, posts, categories

I trying to get all the latest post from every category, but I discovered I must ignore one of them. I don't want to show it at all. My problem is I don't know what syntax to write `ifelse` in this code.

Here is my code :

```
<?php
  while($i<count($output_categories)):

  $latest_cat_post_6 = 
   new WP_Query( array('posts_per_page' => 1,'category__in'=>$output_categories[$i]));

   if($latest_cat_post_6 == 48){
             //do nothung 
             } else {
  if( $latest_cat_post_6->have_posts() ) :
  while( $latest_cat_post_6->have_posts() ) : $latest_cat_post_6->the_post();
    }  
?>
```

Comment: oky ..... thanx @Pieter Goosen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't make sense to me. The easiest way to do this is to use [`get_categories()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories) to get all the categories, and use the **`exclude` parameter to exclude the category that you don't need**. You can then feed that back into a new [`WP_QUERY`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

Example

```
$categories = get_categories( 'exclude=ID_OF_CATEGORY')

foreach ($categories as $category) {

  $new_query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=1&cat=' . $category->cat_ID );

    if($new_query->have_posts()) : 
      while($new_query->have_posts()) : $new_query->the_post();

        // YOUR LOOP ELEMENTS

       endwhile;

       wp_reset_postdata();

     endif;
}
```

Comment: it is work with me .....  yes your one easier but  you don't answer how to ignore or skip one of category in your cod

Comment: I did explain it, please reread my answer carefully. `$categories = get_categories( 'exclude=ID_OF_CATEGORY')`. It is here that you must swop `ID_OF_CATEGORY` with the ID of the category that you want to exclude

Comment: it is work >>>>>> thanx

Comment: My pleasure. Enjoy :-)